# How to build a private app in Adobe Phonegap build service?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am using adobe phonegap build to make a mobile application. The application runs fine in my phonegap desktop app but when I upload zip file to the phonegap build service. And download the .apk file to test on my phone, it somehow overwrites my splash screen with its default splash screen.

Maybe I uploading the wrong folder or something. So which folder exactly do I need to upload ? A zip file of my /application-name folder or /www folder or all files inside my application-name folder? I am confused. Please help.

Comment: You might want to change the title of your question, it's a littel misleading ;)

Answer (score 0):

check your config.xml for proper file paths to the files.

and have a look at [Splash-screen plugin's docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html)

make sure you have added all options as they documented.